# Different ways for passing URL parameters in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to know some other methods for passing parameters through the URL in PHP. I'm aware one could do:

```
mydomain.com/page.php?var1=abc?var2=def
```

and so on. But how could I do:

```
mydomain.com/var1/var2
```

I know the above code does not specify what the current page would be, but one of the variable would be assigned to the page (And the user would be viewing index.php and I would use "includes", I don't need help on this part)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL rewriting is what you are looking for. I think that this tutorial could be a good starting point: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/